# Android: loadData into Webview without repositioning screen

Tags: android, webview

I want to download and load images into Webview as they are downloaded (embedding direct image url's into the HTML is not an option)

When I call the `webView.loadData(myData..` the full page is refreshed and the user's app is repositioned to 0,0 - is there a way where I can append to the HTML with the new image as and when it is downloaded? I am looking for a way to override the functionality of resetting the position of the webView on a call to `loadData`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you handle the problem in JS side by trigering an event to document when the app has downloaded images ?

Like :

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:imagesLoaded()");
```

Comment: i wanted to find an option/parameter but yes, I am doing this now - my android code will call a js function which will use javascript to append to the DOM - will post code here ASAP it's done - thanks!